# Swift: Quickblox trace startcall and get error ( debuging )

Tags: swift, quickblox

I use below code:

```
var sendQb = "XXX"
var sendRoom = "YYY"

var w = QBRTCConferenceType.video

let newSession = QBRTCClient.instance().createNewSession(withOpponents: [NSNumber.init(value: sendQb)], with: w)
var sendUser = [String: String]()
sendUser["room"] = "\(sendRoom)"

self.session = newSession
self.session?.startCall(sendUser)
```

This code work some times, and not work some times!

How i can trace call after `startCall()` ?

I want get result from quickblox for calls before accept. Like:

1- is user connect to quickblox ?

2- is user connect to another user ?

3- is quickblox connect to user ?

And more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quickblox Delegate Methods (swift 4)**

You can do it with Quickblox Delegate methods

```
func session(_ session: QBRTCBaseSession, connectedToUser userID: NSNumber) {
    // Called when connection is established with user.
}

func session(_ session: QBRTCSession, hungUpByUser userID: NSNumber, userInfo: [String : String]? = nil) { 
    // Called when user hung up.
}

func session(_ session: QBRTCSession, userDidNotRespond userID: NSNumber) {
    // Called in case when user did not respond to your call within timeout.
    //default value: 45 seconds
}

func session(_ session: QBRTCSession, acceptedByUser userID: NSNumber, userInfo: [String : String]? = nil) {
    // Called when user hung up.
}

func session(_ session: QBRTCSession, rejectedByUser userID: NSNumber, userInfo: [String : String]? = nil) {
    // Called in case when user rejected you call.
}

func session(_ session: QBRTCBaseSession, receivedRemoteVideoTrack videoTrack: QBRTCVideoTrack, fromUser userID: NSNumber) {
    // Called when receivedRemoteVideoTrack
}

func sessionDidClose(_ session: QBRTCSession) {
    // Called when session is closed.
}

func didReceiveNewSession(_ session: QBRTCSession, userInfo: [String : String]? = nil) {
    // Called when someone started a new session with you.
}
```